# Attempting to access a file with a UNC path from asp.net receives "logon failure" error

Tags: asp.net, unc

When I access a file with a UNC path from asp.net I found the following problem:

```
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Any leads on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have the [Double Hop](http://blogs.msdn.com/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx) problem here.